# I want to tame my budgies but they refuse to come outside of cage!

Tags: budgerigar

I have pair of budgies, I want them to become close to me and trust me, but they don't come outside of the cage easily, male budgie sometimes come out easily and don't pluck my fingers but female budgie gets really aggressive and just refuse to leave the cage, she holds every object of the cage tight with legs and beak, as if she is using all her energy to stay inside the cage!

After getting them out: The female budgie keeps seating at one place, on my desk wires, etc but never on my fingers, while male budgie is easy to handle, he has started to seat on my finger for 4-5 minutes.

Some background: the female budgie was once attacked by a stray cat but she fought well and survived!

Answer (score 1):

Try Placing your hand in their cage with some of their favourite treats on it and leave it there for a little while. Keep doing this and hopefully she will pick up the courage to eat out of your hand. I would also spend loads of time near the cage so they get used to you and your smell. Taming animals, especially birds, can take weeks to do so you will have to be patient and give the birds time.

Don’t force the birds to come out, if they don’t want to come out then they don’t have to. I’d recommend a taming schedule so the birds feel safer because they know what/when it’s coming. It will also help you keep on track.